# PHP, execute public static function from $class

Tags: php, php-7

how to call public static function of class from different namespace in php. I have this code:

```
namespace x\y\z;

use x\y\z\h\Foo;
...
$classinstring = 'Foo';
$classinstring::getType();
```

and i got error that php can't find class Foo `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Foo' not found` how i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

To instantiate a class, you should use `new`.

`$classinstring = new Foo();`

Writing `$classinstring = 'Foo'` assigns `$classinstring` the string literal `"Foo"`.

Namespacing is a shortcut to your classes. These two statements are equal:

```
namespace x\y\z;

use x\y\z\h\Foo;

$bar = new Foo();
```

and

```
$bar = new \x\y\z\h\Foo();
```

Also make sure you have your class names spelled exactly the same as the file name. 

Static methods do not need to be instantiated to be used; you can call them directly from the class name.

`Foo::someCustomMethod()`;

You are using `getType()` as an example, although this is a native PHP global function and cannot be called as a static method, *unless* you have defined your own `getType()` method within the class.

```
class Foo
{
    public function getType()
    {
        echo 'This is my own function.';
    }

    public static function callAnywhere()
    {
        echo 'You don't have to make a new one to use one.';
    }
}
```

This is good if you need to call class methods.

```
Foo::callAnywhere() // prints 'You don't have to make a new one to use one.';

$bar = new Foo();
$bar->getType(); // prints 'This is my own function.'

$other = new stdClass();
echo getType($other); // prints 'object';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
namespace x\y\z;

use x\y\z\h\Foo;
...
$classinstring = 'Foo';
$classinstring = new $classinstring;
$classinstring::getType();
```

OR

Maybe your file just could not find and access the class **x\y\z\h\Foo**. Make sure that your class Foo has the namespace of **namespace \x\y\z\h**.